# Django Rest Framework complex SQL query

Tags: sql, django, api, django-rest-framework, backend

I was asked to create the backend of a project using Django (the frontend is angular).
So I thought about using rest framework but I'm a total beginner and raw sql queries are needed for this project. To be more precise it's a complex query that needs many tables: they provided the sql script that I need to use it directly.

My question is does rest framework allow such raw queries (because I was not able to find a tutorial about that) or do I need something else?

Edit for further explanation:
I'm I able to return complex queries in rest framework as a GET request for example? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Django ORM can make very complex queries, you may want to check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `raw` function to make it

```py
Model.objects.raw("WRITE YOUR SQL HERE")
```

Comment: Does this work in rest framework? my main problem is how to return the result of the query as a GET request for example

Comment: this doesn't have any relation with rest framework it's the same as using ```filter```

Comment: add more details ... what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor connection for direct execute SQL query.

```
from django.db import connection

def my_query(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    row = cursor.fetchall()

return row
```

Comment: Does this work in rest framework? my main problem is how to return the result of the query as a GET request for example